# How to configure ORMLite to save `byte[]` as DataType.BYTE_ARRAY?

Tags: java, database, jpa, persistence, ormlite

In my db entities i have `byte[]` fields:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 *  Account
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = TABLE)
public class Account {
    public static final String TABLE = "Account";
    ...

    public final static String COLUMN_PASSWORD_HASH = "passwordHash";
    @Column(name = COLUMN_PASSWORD_HASH, nullable = false)
    public byte[] passwordHash;

    ...
```

I want to keep my db entities clear of any vendor dependency so i use only JPA annotations and try to avoid any ORMLite or Hibernate annotations.

However when trying to save such entity with ORMLite i get the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORMLite does not know how to store class [B for field 'passwordHash'. byte[] fields must specify dataType=DataType.BYTE_ARRAY or SERIALIZABLE

As far as i understand for some reason ORMLite does not prefer BYTE_ARRAY for `byte[]` and requires to mark the fields with `com.j256.ormlite.field.Datatype` ORMLite annotation with introduces explicit dependency on `ormlite-core` module and this is what i want to avoid (i have Hibernate DAO impl and ORMLite DAO impl and i don't want to mix everything).

My original intention was to configure ORMLite to prefer `BYTE_ARRAY` for `byte[]` fields. How can i do it? Should i introduce custom persister? Any other suggestions?

Comment: FYI: ORMLite initially treated `byte[]` as `Serializable` and I didn't want it to arbitrarily change types so I forced users to pick one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding the following custom data persister (without adding dependency to `ormlite-core` as i wanted):

```
package name.antonsmirnov.zzz.dao.types;

import com.j256.ormlite.field.SqlType;
import com.j256.ormlite.field.types.ByteArrayType;

/**
 * ByteArray Type that prefers storing byte[] as BYTE_ARRAY
 */
public class PreferByteArrayType extends ByteArrayType {

    public PreferByteArrayType() {
        super(SqlType.BYTE_ARRAY, new Class[] { byte[].class });
    }

    private static final PreferByteArrayType singleTon = new PreferByteArrayType();

    public static PreferByteArrayType getSingleton() {
        return singleTon;
    }
}
```

Register it just like any other custom persister:

```
DataPersisterManager.registerDataPersisters(PreferByteArrayType.getSingleton());
```

Note you can't use default `ByteArrayDataType` because it has empty `classes` array so it causes it to become persister for autogenerated fields and it throws exception that byte array fields can't be id fields.

I've checked it to use `BLOB` fields type for MySQL:

> com.mysql.jdbc.Field@39a2bb97[catalog=test_db,tableName=account,originalTableName=account,columnName=passwordHash,originalColumnName=passwordHash,mysqlType=252(FIELD_TYPE_BLOB),flags= BINARY BLOB, charsetIndex=63, charsetName=ISO-8859-1]